# JBOSS MDC for every request including thread pool

Tags: logging, jboss, ip-address, mdc

i am using JBOSS EAP 7, using MDC i am able to track to my IPAddress for every `ServletRequest` using 
 `MDC.put("IPAddress",.getInetAddress())` 
but only for parent thread, not for child thread how can achieve for child threads

Comment: What logging framework are you using? By that I mean, which MDC implementation.

Comment: JBOSS and log4j(not 2)

Comment: How are you creating threads? Are you excluding log4j and providing your own or are you using the servers log4j module?